# Multi-tenancy - Create tables up-front or as needed?

Tags: php, mysql, saas, multi-tenant, mysql-error-1146

I'm currently working on a SaaS type application, and for multi-tenancy I've settled on one database per user, with each database containing all tables required by the functionality the user is entitled to (have payed for).
The application is designed to capture data (i.e. like web analytics) and present it for the user. The design should be able to scale to the tens of thousands of users (eventually).

Would a viable solution be to create the tables 'dynamically' when the application detects they are required? Or should I create all *eventually* required tables in specific user databases, as soon as I know they *may* be needed (user upgrade, new features, etc.)?

My current architecture would allow me to do something like this:

```
function insertData($table, $data) {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO ".$table." VALUES ('".implode("', '", $data)."')");
    if ( mysql_errno() ) {
      if (mysql_errno() == 1146) { // table does not exist
        if ( $this->createTable($table) ) {
          $this->insertData($table, $data)
        }
      } else {
        // other errors
      }
    }
}
```

I would like the flexibility to be able to add functionality without having to loop through all user databases to add tables, so a setup like the above would help me achive that. But I'm not sure if I'm missing something that would make me regret the decision later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an insert to test whether a table exists may not be your best bet, particularly considering the size of the row and latency to the database server.  A better solution might be to use 'show tables', i.e.:

```
SHOW TABLES LIKE 'TABLENAME';
```

The resultset will be something like this:

```
Tables_in_DATABASENAME (TABLENAME)
----------------------------------
be_groups
```

If the number of rows is zero, clearly the table does not exist.

As far as your process is concerned -- I think I'd take a hybrid approach.  When the customer upgrades and as part of your provisioning workflow create all the tables needed to provide the new services to the customer.  That way the customer doesn't take up any more resources (disk mainly, in this case) than they're paying for, and you're not causing yourself the pain of provisioning dynamically.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The benefit of the code i wrote was, that the test if the table existed was only done if the query gave an error in the first place. As soon as the table is created, the initial INSERT query would run error free. Having SHOW TABLES, would require that i checked everytime an INSERT runs.
I agree with with our comment on creating tables on upgrades, but I would then still have to loop through all databases if new functionality is added to system.

Comment: Not necessarily, depending on how your account structure is set.  I read 'loop through all databases' as 'check each database regardless of the user's account level';  in reality, you already know which databases need upgrading, based on the user's ACLs.  If you're concerned with server load for the upgrade, creating empty tables takes almost no load -- mysql is basically creating files and updating indices.  Even so, you could consider a staggered deployment and/or a dedicated maintenance window.

Comment: I'll admit the insert/error/create cycle vs provisioning may be more personal choice than anything else, but it feels to me a lot like placing a glass of juice on a table that isn't there, noticing the spill, going to go get a table, and starting over.  Easier to look at the table first.